# How do I make my Python errors point to the exact thing that's causing the error?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

Take the following very simple code:

```py
x = "test string"
y = isinstance(X, str) # Intentionally misspelled x
```

If I run this code, I get this error:

```
    y = isinstance(X, str)
                   ^
NameError: name 'X' is not defined. Did you mean: 'x'?
```

What I want to know is how would I go about making my errors point to the exact thing that's causing the error (like in this case, the undefined variable passed `X`), and if it can't do that, it should fallback to the line that's causing the error.

I have seen lots of projects that utilise this, so I know it's possible, but I don't know how. I would appreciate some help on this, or perhaps a library I can use.

---

Here are my exception classes:

```py
class StaticvarException(Exception):
    '''
    Base class for staticvar exceptions.

    Args:
        message (str): error message.
    '''
    def __init__(self, message: str):
        super().__init__(message)


class UnsupportedTypeError(StaticvarException):
    '''
    Should be raised when a non-standarad type or an unsupported type is specified.

    Args:
        message (str): error message.
    '''
    def __init__(self, message: str):
        super().__init__(message)
```

and here is an example of them being used:

```py
full_name = f"{func.__name__}.{var_name.encode('unicode_escape').decode()}"

# Checking if the type specified is not a valid type or a generic type from the typing module
var_origin = get_origin(var_type)
var_args = get_args(var_type)

if not (isclass(var_type) or
        (var_origin is not None and isinstance(var_origin, type)) or
        (var_args is not None and len(var_args) > 0)):
    raise UnsupportedTypeError(
        f"{full_name}: "
        f"variable type must be a valid type or a generic type from the typing module. "
        f"Type specified: {var_type}"
    )
```

Thanks in advance.